# is it possible to show a logged-in frontend user all the events they are registered for?

Tags: civievent, joomla, online-registration

I'm wondering if it's possible to create something like a frontend information portal where a user can review their existing registration data.  Such as, user logs in, user can see a list of all the events they are registered for, then can click on an event to see what selections/options they chose when they registered.

Is this possible out of the box? I'm on a Joomla 3.9 system using CiviCRM 5.13, and I don't see a menu item or similar that will accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for the Contact Dashboard feature. I have only experience with Wordpress, where the logged in user can see his memberships, events, payments, invoices etc.

There seems to be a similar feature available for Joomla as well according to [this question on StackExchange](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20702/configuring-front-end-contact-dashboard-in-joomla-sites). Unfortunately the question has been unanswered.

Comment: Thanks! That's the info I was looking for. I'll see if I can get it working under Joomla and report back :-)

Comment: So this seems to work, but it doesn't show everything I'm looking for. The user can see the Events she's registered for, and total cost, but can't see details on what options she chose when registering.

Comment: I am not using events myself, so I cannot verify this possible workaround: If those event options are detailed in the invoices for the events, then users could re-download those invoices from the contact dashboard. - But this feels definitely less straight forward and providing the info directly as part of the event data is much more preferable.

Comment: Hmm thanks for the interesting idea, Joachim.  Maybe if I can't show the individual options I could display the invoice instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am totally unfamiliar with Joomla so I am not aware if there are similar possibilities to the Drupal Webform CiviCRM module. But with CiviCRM profiles I would imagine you would be able to build this?

Have you checked the User Guide on profiles here" https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/? That might be of help.

Comment: I thought about using profiles, but I'm not sure if I can expose all the Participant/Event info I need to access using profiles?

Comment: Confirmed, I can't expose specific details of what price set options they chose for each event through profiles :-(